# Creating a VS2012 Style ListView/Stack Panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a MVVM WPF application and I want to create a start screen similar in style the one in VS2012 (shown below)

[image: ListVS2012]

I would like to create a ListView, or stack panel like that for the recent documents in the image above. I would like to do this using a `DataTemplate` so that I can use the control in other areas of the application.

In WinForms, I would design a user control, but in WPF I am confused as to the best way to do this. I have considered using a resource file that contains the data template and a converter for the pinned/un-pinned image

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="imageWithTextBlockTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource booleanToImageConverter}}" 
                                Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="16"/> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is not finished (clearly), but is this the right approach, or is there a better/more standard way of doing such things?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not design a UserControl in WPF?

Comment: I could do, but I was under the impression that to get an image and text in a list view I can't use existing controls and have to create my own. Long and short, I am a tad confused as of the right approach to take...

Comment: Sorry, my comment was quite flippant. I actually think your proposed solution of using a DataTemplate is perfectly sound and more "WPF" than writing a whole new control.

Comment: I think, instead of the `StackPanel`, you can use the `ToggleButton`. As `IsChecked = "False"` Pin not, as `IsChecked = "True"` Pin is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create control's that look similar to VS2012, best place to figure out "how to" is pretty much in VS2012. Remember VS2012 is made with WPF.

So if you get [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and analyse the "Start Page", you should see something like:

[image]

As you can see it is indeed a `ListBox` that which is being used.

They then have the DataTemplate as a `Grid` with a custom `CheckBox` to hold the "pinned" status and then to the right is another `Grid` to hold the project icon(`Image`) and name(`TextBlock`).

**Update:**

As for the `CheckBox`, they use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ImageCheckBox`. Now you could either fire up reflector to get the exact definition or say based on Snoop's data, it looks like this control holds a `Border` and an `Image` within it.

`Image` source it uses are such as:

```
pack://application:,,,/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0;component/UI/Images/pinned normal.png

pack://application:,,,/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0;component/UI/Images/unpinned normal.png
```

Now as for your implementation with this info,

- I'd have each item of the collection in your VM, hold the `Text` and `IsPinned` status.
- Next, Create a custom `CheckBox` Style and modify it's `ControlTemplate` to hold an Image or a Border with image.
- use the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` to check the `IsChecked` property and accordingly modify the `Image.Source` to switch between various "pinned" images
- With this in, You can have your `DataTemplate` for `ListBox.ItemTemplate` pretty much with a `StackPanel`(`Orientation="Horizontal"`) with 2 children. First a Checkbox using the above created custom `Style` and second a `TextBlock`.
- Finally bind the `CheckBox.IsChecked` in the `DataTemplate` with `{Binding IsPinned}` and `TextBlock.Text` with `{Binding Text}`

that should be pretty much it. You'd have to ofc also tweak `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to get rid of say the default mouse-over effect from the ListBox and probably also set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` but they ain't really part of your `DataTemplate`